# Is there any system table which captures Redshift query console output?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am loading data from s3 to Redshift for more than 60 tables.
Data present in s3 is not clean, so I am using MAXERROR "Err_count" to load data into Redshift.
Although my data is getting loaded but some of records are getting missed, and I get info like:
    Warning: Load into table 'xyz' completed, N record(s) could not be loaded.

Does Redshift maintain any System table where I can query and get this warning message per session for all the executed queries?

Answer (score 0):

You can query the `STL_LOAD_ERRORS` table for general information on the errors issued by COPY commands in Redshift [1], and the table `STL_LOADERROR_DETAIL` for any additional details on the same errors [2].

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_STL_LOAD_ERRORS.html

[2] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_STL_LOADERROR_DETAIL.html